# Craft CMS ajax query for Entry associated with Category

Tags: php, yii

I am sending a AJAx request to the server to query for all "properties" that are related to a certain category "destination".

The field in the entry is called Destination with the handle "destinationCategories"

My code currently looks like this;

```
public function actionGetLocation()
{

        $locationId = craft()->request->getParam('id');

       // Find the Actual Category Object from The DB, I did this just in case I need to query based on title, or something else
       // The correct category is being returned

        $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Category);
        $criteria->id = $locationId;
        $criteria->limit = null;
        $selectedCategory = $criteria->first();
        unset($criteria);


        $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);

        // I am now attempting to query for 
        // destinationCategories = the category that I have queried from the DB


        $criteria->destinationCategories = $selectedCategory->id;
        $criteria->limit = null;

        $properties = $criteria->find();


        var_dump($properties);

        foreach($properties as $property)
        {
            echo $property->title;
        }
        exit;
        return $this->returnJson(array('status' => 'ok', 'options' => $subCategories));
}
```

The query is returning null even when results are available

Where am i going wrong I have tried

```
$criteria->destinationCategories = $selectedCategory->id;
$criteria->destinationCategories = $selectedCategory->title;
$criteria->destinationCategories = $selectedCategory->slug;
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you would have completed this project till now :) but to solve this could you try not to unset $criteria until you use any depending variable. Once your usage is done unset the variable.